# Relation between the probability of infection and transmission rate in SIR model

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to link between the transmission rate in SIR Model and the probability of infection.
I have found in a research paper that for a transmission rate $r$ and an average recovery time $t$, the probability of infection can be considered a poisson process, thus the probability of infection $p$ is equal to $1 - exp(-rt)$.
I'm having a difficulty understanding the intuition behind this.